# How to cast System.Object[*] to System.Object[]

Tags: c#, interop, casting, visual-foxpro

When I Tried to return an `Array` in VFP9 language COM/DLL to my .NET C# project
I receive a `System.Object[*]` array and I can not cast to `System.Object[]` (Without asterisk).

Comment: What is an `Object[*]`? Do you mean an `Object*` as in an unmanaged pointer to an Object array?

Comment: @Callum: No, it is a System.Array with a non-zero starting index.

Comment: Yes @Callum, so How I can work with this?

Comment: @Timwi: Yikes, you can have arrays (as in real `System.Array` s) that don't start at zero? As in they would give an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you tried to access the zeroth element? How is this useful?

Comment: @Cheva: So it is a pointer problem then... do you know the size of the array or is it null terminated?

Comment: @Callum: Yes, although the only way to access such an array in C# is to use `Array.GetValue()`, and yes, you would get the `IndexOutOfRangeException`. The reason the CLR supports such arrays is because of VB.NET.

Comment: (Also, I doubt Cheva knew what they were saying when they answered your question with “yes”. I don’t think it’s a pointer problem.)

Comment: @Timwi: That's why I haven't answered. I'm guessing this VFP language uses arrays starting at 1 or some other value.

Comment: @Callum Rogers, hopefully it isn't "some other value"... An array that starts at 42 would be really weird ;) (although you can create such an array in C#...)

Comment: (I have once had a reasonable usecase for an array that starts at −1.)

Answer (score 9):

Timwi's solution should work fine. You can do something a bit simpler using Linq:

```
object[] newArray = sourceArray.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

In case you need to recreate a `System.Object[*]` to pass it back to VFP, you can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=net-7.0#system-array-createinstance(system-type-system-int32()-system-int32())) of the `Array.CreateInstance` method:

```
public static Array CreateInstance(
    Type elementType,
    int[] lengths,
    int[] lowerBounds
)
```

You can use it as follows:

```
object[] normalArray = ...

// create array with lower bound of 1
Array arrayStartingAt1 =
    Array.CreateInstance(
        typeof(object),
        new[] { normalArray.Length },
        new[] { 1 });

Array.Copy(normalArray, 0, arrayStartingAt1, 1, normalArray.Length);
```

Comment: Somehow I never think of the solutions which are shorter but much slower. I realise that in most cases the performance penalty is insignificant...

Comment: Does this work because the `Cast` can simply iterate over the array using an IEnumerator instead of worrying where the array starts? If so couldn't you just use `Select(x => x).ToArray()` (or even just`ToArray()` ) instead? It would remove the need for a cast from `object` to `object`.

Comment: Indeed, it will be a bit slower. When the source sequence implements `ICollection<T>`, `ToArray` takes advantage of that, but arrays with non-zero bounds only implements the non-generic `ICollection`...

Comment: @Callum Rogers, yes, exactly. `Array` implements `IEnumerable`

Comment: You MASTER!. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Myself: You can't just use `ToArray()` or `Select()` because `Array` only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` and they both require `IEnumerable<T>`. +1 for this answer for cleverness.

Comment: What happens if I have a method like `public int ReadFPGA( out object[*] param, ...)` in a dll, where the run-time version is 4.0.x? The project and all other dll is 4.5.2., only this one is 4.0.x.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you cannot cast it directly. You can, however, create a new array of type `object[]` and copy the data over. Something like...

```
Array sourceArray = ...;

if (sourceArray.Rank != 1)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected a single-rank array.");

object[] newArray = new object[sourceArray.Length];
Array.Copy(sourceArray, sourceArray.GetLowerBound(0),
           newArray, 0, sourceArray.Length);
```

Comment: Great, this works, but if you have thousands of items, you think?
'll Keep testing with queries or grades.

Comment: googling I find a VFP instruction for this from VFP source code: the function ComArray(This.newArray, 10) that pass to based zero. the inverse method

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. Got an array as a `dynamic` object from an interop assembly, also starting from index one. When I tried to convert this into an `Array` object, I got the same error message.
Doing as the other answers suggest did not work. For a strange reason, even reading the `Length` property raised the exception.
I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d8c0e5f-792d-4072-a944-c5d58c0eac70/giving-the-errorunable-to-cast-object-of-type-systemobject-to-type-systemobject?forum=vsto) answer, and it worked.
Apparently, if you use C# 4.0, you have to cast the `dynamic` to `object` first, then you can convert it to `Array`. In prior versions of .NET you can cast directly.
Here is an [Explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mshneer/2010/06/01/oh-that-mysteriously-broken-visiblesliceritemslist/) why.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  All the other stuff doesn't work with a dynamic.

Comment: Up-voted. Very good information which I also discovered now myself. See so-called [thread II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366984/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue when reading arrays dynamically from an API which returns data from a non-.NET platform which supports arbitrary ranges for array indexes (IEC 61131-3 PLC programming language arrays). This platform also supports *multi-dimensional* arrays with *different lower bounds for each dimension*!

Here's the code I wrote to convert the arrays. It works for both 1d and multi-dimensional arrays with arbitrary lower bounds, converting them to a .NET array of the same underlying type, rank, and shape.

```
public static Array ConvertToZeroBaseIndexes(this Array arrayValue)
{
    // If it's already a zero-based array, just return it instead of doing a pointless array copy
    if ((arrayValue.Rank == 1 && arrayValue.GetLowerBound(0) == 0) ||
        Enumerable.Range(0, arrayValue.Rank).All(dimension => arrayValue.GetLowerBound(dimension) == 0))
    {
        return arrayValue;
    }

    Type? arrayElementType = arrayValue.GetType().GetElementType();
    if (arrayElementType == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot convert array of unknown type");

    var dimensionSizes = Enumerable.Range(0, arrayValue.Rank)
        .Select(dimension => arrayValue.GetUpperBound(dimension) - arrayValue.GetLowerBound(dimension) + 1)
        .ToArray();

    Int32 elementCount = dimensionSizes.Aggregate((product, dimensionSize) => product * dimensionSize);

    var target = Array.CreateInstance(arrayElementType, dimensionSizes);
    Array.Copy(arrayValue, target, elementCount);

    return target;
}
```