# How to cast System.Object[*] to System.Object[] II

Tags: c#, casting, com-interop

I have got a similar problem like Cheva had in his Question:

[How to cast System.Object[*] to System.Object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731287/how-to-cast-system-object-to-system-object)

I use an external library (Reuters EIKON API) via the COM interop functionality.

After submitting a request, the object gets updated and its data member gets updated. The Object catalogue shows this for the Data member:

```
public virtual dynamic Data { get; }
```

In the debug mode, I can see, that after submitting the request, DataStatus changes to dataset_full and the Data member is actually  filled.

The data member is shown as {object[1..31]} and I can see from the debug dropdown menu, that there a actually strings in this collection.

My problem is that I can't access this object. I can cast it to `object[]` or `string[]` or anything. I can't even find out the type of it.

It always says `System.Object[*]` can not be cast to `System.Object[]`

if I try to find out the type by using .Type(), I get "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException". I even cannot access the Length of it, this also gives me the error

```
System.InvalidCastException -> Object of Type "System.Object[*]" cannot be cast to type "System.Object[]"
```

Has anyone seen a similar error?

Comment: Can you include your code you used for casting so we can see what you tried?

Comment: are you trying to cast a dynamic to an object[]?

Comment: It is a non-conformant array with a lower-bound that is not 0.  Not uncommon in COM interop, starting at 1 is fairly typical.  You can only cast to (Array).  And use its GetLowerBound() method to know where to start indexing, GetUpperBound() to know where to stop, GetValue() to read an element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does System.Double\[\*\] mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125903/what-does-system-double-mean)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem here working VSTO.  Excel.Filter.Criteria1 is dynamic, filter returns an "object[]" but behaves exactly as you've stated..  can't loop, no methods, properties, fields, members, nothing.  Once dynamic has it, it can't be stored on another dynamic object.  Use your 1 shot wisely!

Comment: @LeoGurdian Your comments here and to my answer made me look into this again, and I found out I wanted to provide more information on the particular cocktail of using `dynamic` together with an actual type of `System.Object[*]`. So check out my expanded answer.

Answer (score 4):

`System.Object[*]` is a `System.Array` which is one-dimensional but not indexed starting from `0`. It is not well supported in C#, because C# uses 0-based indexing.

A `System.Object[*]` is not an `object[]`, so you can't cast to that type.

You can use:

```
var dataAsArray = (Array)Data;
```

or

```
var dataAsNonGenericIList = (IList)Data;
```

Then you can **`foreach`** through it.

Or you can access individual entries by index, like this:

```
object first = dataAsArray.GetValue(1);
```

respectively:

```
object first = dataAsNonGenericIList[1];
```

You will need to work out the upper and lower bounds (`dataAsArray.GetLowerBound(0)`, `dataAsArray.GetUpperBound(0)`), but it seems that the lower bound is `1` in your case.

You can cast to `string` in the usual ways, `(string)first` if you expect it to be a string every time, or something like `first as string` (then check for null) if you want to support other objects.

---

If instead you want to *copy* the "weird" array to a 0-indexed array, see the linked thread without the numeral `II` in the title. Indexes will change, of course. For example `object[] newArray = new object[dataAsArray.Length]; dataAsArray.CopyTo(newArray, 0);`

---

**Much** later edit:

In addition to what I wrote above, there is a bug in the run-time binder used with C# `dynamic` functionality when the actual type is `System.Object[*]`. This could also be inferred from the question above. As an example (the array I create has rank one, the length of the sole dimension is `31`, and the lower bound in that dimension is `1` (i.e. not zero-indexed)):

```
dynamic Data = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new[] { 31, }, new[] { 1, });
dynamic t = Data.GetType(); // throws!
dynamic s = Data.ToString(); // throws!
```

In either case an `InvalidCastException` is thrown:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[*]' to type 'System.Object[]'.

This is a bug, I would say. The members exist, and I did not ask to cast to that type, I asked for late-binding to members that exist.

*The very same bug occurs at run-time when I cast directly from `dynamic` to `Array` or `IList`, as I did above in the original answer.*

You can work around this bug in the following way:

```
var dataAsArray = (Array)(object)Data;
```

and:

```
var dataAsNonGenericIList = (IList)(object)Data;
```

Casting to `object` with late binding (i.e. from `dynamic`) does not appear to be affected by the bug. The the next cast, from `object` to `Array` (or to `IList`), is a normal down-cast with no `dynamic` magic, and that works of course.

With this, my answer has become useful (years later).

I am just realizing that [an answer by RoadBump in a linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41227268/1336654) also gives this information, so go up-vote that answer.

Comment: very well put, weird arrays.  Thanks for shedding light but the thing is they contain no methods, members, fields, nothing just a list of "strings" as in my case as well.  you can't even loop thru so unfortunately, your suggestions won't work. : (