# Retrieve the correct value from System.Object[*]

Tags: c#, casting, vsto, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm building a VSTO Excel add-in, I would like to use `Evaluate` to evaluate Excel formulas.

With the following code, when there are some values in `A1:A20`, it returns a correct result. For instance, if A1 has `3` as value, in the output, it shows `System.Object[,]`, then we can further cast it.

```
Excel.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
object result = app.Evaluate("=UNIQUE(A1:A20)");
Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

However, when `A1:A20` are empty, in the output, it shows `System.Object[*]`.

Does anyone know what `System.Object[*]` is? How could I cast such values to get the correct result (e.g., `0` for `=UNIQUE(A1:A20)` when `A1:A20` are empty)?

Comment: Did you try to google the answer? basically the first two results seem to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539231/what-is-this-object-type-i-get-with-com-interop | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731287/how-to-cast-system-object-to-system-object - or don't they?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this \`Object\[\*\]\` type I get with COM interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539231/what-is-this-object-type-i-get-with-com-interop)

Comment: I got confused with those answers (though I keep trying one by one). Hope somebody could propose a specific answer for my specific question.

Comment: But what is your issue, to be precise? - the answers are basically copy & paste ready, without knowing why the answer don't fit your need, we can't help any further: https://dotnetfiddle.net/36wZKV

Comment: @RandRandom Thank you. I don't understand in which cases we need `object[] resultArray = array.Cast<object>().ToArray();`?

Comment: every time you don't want to deal with a `System.Array` but instead the more commonly known `object[]` - it is just code to turn `System.Array` into `object[]` - maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657591

Comment: though I want to point out, which type of array you are actually dealing with is unknown - as is described in the question linked of my previous comment `System.Array` is the base class of all array so it could be any form of array eg. single, jagged... - see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Do8mJv - the code you mentioned assumes you are dealing with a single dimension array, but that assumption could be wrong

Comment: The result of `Evaluate` can indeed be two-dimensional.